# cordova fcm push notifications using firebase functions issue

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am using firebase function and sending the notification like below

```
 let pushPayload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Doodles Notification',
            body: "push testing",
            sound: 'default',
            badge: '1'
            }
    };

    //push tokens need to be of customer as well as all the admins in the system. fetch admin push tokens
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(pushToken, pushPayload).then(
        (resp) => {
                        console.log("push notification sent using test method")
                        return
                }
    ).catch(
        (err) => {
                    console.log("Error sending push notification:" + JSON.stringify(err))
                    return
        }
    )
```

The client side ionic app has method like below:

```
  this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
            console.log("push message is:" + JSON.stringify(data))
            alert(data.aps.alert.body)
          });
```

on ios this all works great. however on android, the console.log prints

```
{"wasTapped":false}
```

I am ok with the above expected property but where is the data? The firebase documentation is confusing around it and I am sort of lost what is the correct payload I need to use that works with both ios and android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `pushPayload` also needs to have a `data` array to pass data. I believe you also need speech marks around your keys:

```
"notification":{  
   "title":"Doodles Notification",
   "body":"push testing",
   "sound":"default",
   "badge":"1"
},
"data":{  
   "Key1":"Test",
   "Key2":"More data"
}
```

[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Comment: is that an android specific requirement? in ios my code work just fine with required data

Comment: I'm not sure I'm afraid, don't have much iOS experience. Have you tried adding the data array?

Comment: i am about to try this